# Need advice on including OpenGL/GLUT in makefile

Tags: ros, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

update: I added OpenCV but still same error.

in my package.xml i have

```
 <build_depend>OpenGL</build_depend>
```

in my Cmakefile i have

```
include_directories(include 
                    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${TinyXML_INCLUDE_DIRS}

target_link_libraries(ar_track_alvar ${OpenGL_LIBRARIES)  ${TinyXML_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

but i get the error:

```
make[1]: *** [ar_track_alvar/ar_track_alvar/CMakeFiles/individualMarkersNoKinect.dir/all] Error 2
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutSpecialFunc'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutMouseFunc'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `alvar::CameraEC::UpdatePose(CvMat const*, CvMat*, alvar::Pose*, CvMat*)'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutSetWindow'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `alvar::CameraEC::Get3dOnPlane(alvar::Pose const*, CvPoint2D32f, CvPoint3D32f&)'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutPositionWindow'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutInit'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
/home/richard/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libar_track_alvar.so: undefined reference to `glutMotionFunc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204792/need-advice-on-including-opengl/glut-in-makefile/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While your own approach works, I wouldn't recommend it, as you are hardcoding the name of the GLUT library and making assumptions about its presence on your system.

You only included a few lines of your `CMakeLists.txt`, so you could already be doing this, but just as an example (only showing relevant parts):

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED ..)

find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

..

# setup include path for both OpenGL & GLUT (and other dependencies)
include_directories(
  include 
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ..
)

..

# now link target against all required libs
target_link_libraries(
  ar_track_alvar
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
    ${GLUT_LIBRARY}
    ..
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Then also add a `build_depend` on `glut` (which is the `rosdep` key for Glut according to [rosindex/d/glut](http://rosindex.github.io/d/glut/)).

Finally, be sure to add both `OpenGL` and `GLUT` (and any other system dependencies that you are using) to the `DEPENDS` argument of `catkin_package(..)`.

> in my package.xml i have
>
> ```
> <build_depend>OpenGL</build_depend>
> ```

According to [rosindex/d/opengl](http://rosindex.github.io/d/opengl/), the `rosdep` key is actually `opengl` (all lowercase).

---

Edit:

> opengl lower case only shows in QT library while OpenGL shows in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenGL

`rosdep` keys do not have to correspond in any way to any 'real' library, file, directory or package. They are simply a key into a database that maps to platform specific pkgs.

The `rosdep` key for all packages that provide OpenGL dev hdrs/libs on all supported platforms is really `opengl` (see [rosdep/base.yaml, lines 2522 to 2531](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/956944905a6a66202fddc87be93175f6fddf6ac7/rosdep/base.yaml#L2522-L2531)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-03-12**:
opengl lower case only shows in QT library
while OpenGL shows in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenGL